# How to remove an element from AngularJS dynamic form?

Tags: jquery, forms, angularjs, dynamicform

Please check this Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kgXRa/

Here is the code (Implemented in the JSFiddle)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.field = [];
    $scope.value = [];
    $scope.inputCounter = 0;
}]);

app.directive('addInput', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.find('button').bind('click', function () {
                var input = angular.element('<div><input type="text" ng-model="field[' + scope.inputCounter + ']"><input type="text" ng-model="value[' + scope.inputCounter + ']"> <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="remove_it(' + scope.inputCounter + ')">remove</a></div> ');

                var compile = $compile(input)(scope);
                element.append(input);
                scope.inputCounter++;
                scope.remove_it = function(scope_counter) {
                   compile.remove(this);
                   scope.inputCounter--;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

I need to add the remove button when user creates the new fields. Somehow I need to drop the counter so the Array is cleared up as user delete the input.
I have tried to use jQuery however I think there should be a way in Angular.JS

With the script I wrote it remove the wrong one.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why don't you just use an ng-repeat to generate your fields on the fly? You shouldn't really be creating or removing dom nodes like this when it can easily be done with core angular code

Comment: I know we are here to answer the question people have, but what should we do, when we see that the question does not matter as the rest of the code is just bad practice? should we just answer what he wants or should we tell him. I think there should be a SO feature exactly fot this

Comment: @Luke I personally prefer if someone correct me if I am implementing a wrong practice. I always correct ones practice instead of just solving his/her problem. Thanks. I would appreciate if you show me a better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example of how you could accomplish this in a more "Angular way".

Your rows are stored as a single array of objects having a pair of properties, and you have two functions for adding and removing rows.

```
$scope.inputs = [];

$scope.addInput = function(){
    $scope.inputs.push({field:'', value:''});
}

$scope.removeInput = function(index){
    $scope.inputs.splice(index,1);
}
```

In your view, you iterate over your array of objects using ng-repeat and the data automatically appears and disappears as you click the buttons.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    [<span ng-repeat="input in inputs">"{{input.field}}"</span>]:
    [<span ng-repeat="input in inputs">"{{input.value}}"</span>]
    <div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
        <input type="text" ng-model="input.field" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="input.value" />
        <button ng-click="removeInput($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addInput()">add input</button>
</div>
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A6G5r/

Comment: Thanks the jsfiddle is not the correct one as I cant see your changes in it. Not it is matter mate, I got the picture. :) unless I am going mad. please check this fiddle to see if it is what it is meant to be: http://jsfiddle.net/A6G5r/

Comment: Sorry, I must have forgot to fork the fiddle I posted.  I've updated my answer to link to yours (it looks the same as what I had).