# AngularJS ng-click creates child scope but pushes to main scope after subsequent ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I use my first ng-click it creates a child scope but won't push it to parent scope.
Later when I use ng-click again (a very simple seemingly unrelated function) it then seems to jump into main scope and carry out my previous request.

Any ideas? I'm stumped but assume its to do with listeners or watch.

FIRST ng-click:

```
ng-click="cart.addItem(product.sku, product.name, product.price, 1)

 shoppingCart.prototype.addItem = function (sku, name, price, quantity) {

        this.item = [];  
        this.item = {
          sku : sku,
          name :name,
          price : price,
          quantity:quantity

        };
        this.items.push(this.item);


    };
```

SECOND ng-click:

```
ng-click="upload = true"
```

Thanks,

Will

Comment: If you could provide a working Plunker, we could easily work on it

Comment: please take your time to review the answers and choose a correct one (or add your solution, if different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need create a directive, bind a click parameter to put it on DIV element. [This user did a similar code (by Jerrad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819116/how-to-remove-an-element-from-angularjs-dynamic-form) .

Comment: Thanks. I didn't ask a very clear question, but your link has pointed me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go through Angular tutorial, you seem a little bit confused: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

Anyway, you have several problems with your code and some *obscure* parts

I don't know what this  `shoppingCart` is, but as a general rule you can surely substitute this

```
 shoppingCart.prototype.addItem = function (...)
```

with

```
 shoppingCart.addItem = function (...)
```

Then, in your code you have this snippet:

```
    // everytime you run this function, you substitute whatever 
    // item was with an empty array
    this.item = [];  

    // then you substitute the empty array with an object (?)
    this.item = {
      sku : sku,
      name :name,
      price : price,
      quantity:quantity

    };

    // then you try to push your object in a non-existent array, 
    // or in the array you just overwrote (if you meant 'item' instead of 'items')...
    this.items.push(this.item);
```

This code cannot work, so if you see some changes in the `$scope` it should be for some other reason.